# gitweb- fatal: not a git repository

Tags: git, gitolite

So I have set up a simple server running debian stable (squeeze), and have configured git.
Using gitolite, I have all functionality (at least the basic clone/push/pull/commit) working.
Installation of gitweb went without any issues.  However, when I access gitweb, I get a gitweb screen without any repos listed.

```
# tail -n 1 /var/log/apache2/error.log
[DATE] [error] [client IP_ADDRESS] fatal: Not a git repository: '/var/lib/gitolite/repositories/testrepo.git'

# cd /var/lib/gitolite/repositories/testrepo.git
# ls
branches  config  HEAD  hooks  info  objects  refs
```

Here is what I see in `/var/lib/gitolite/projects.list`:

```
testrepo.git
```

And in `/etc/gitweb.conf`:

```
# path to git projects (<project>.git)
$projectroot = "/var/lib/gitolite/repositories";

# directory to use for temp files
$git_temp = "/tmp";

# target of the home link on top of all pages
#$home_link = $my_uri || "/";

# html text to include at home page
$home_text = "indextext.html";

# file with project list; by default, simply scan the projectroot dir.
$projects_list = "/var/lib/gitolite/projects.list";

# stylesheet to use
$stylesheet = "gitweb.css";

# javascript code for gitweb
$javascript = "gitweb.js";

# logo to use
$logo = "git-logo.png";

# the 'favicon'
$favicon = "git-favicon.png";
```

What is missing?

EDIT:  Figured it out, when I had chmod'd the repository I had forgotten to add the -R switch!  I changed the umask but this was not retroactive... and forgot that chmod would only change the directory and not any of the contents.

@VonC, thank you for your config.  Though configuration wasn't the issue, I did get some good ideas beyond my very minimal current config.  I'd vote you up, but I can't yet.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my "gitweb-gitolite" configuration, hoping that may help you find what is missing in your configuration:

I have included my `gitweb.conf.pl` at then end of `gitweb_config.perl` (as mentioned in the [gitolite doc](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite/blob/pu/doc/3-faq-tips-etc.mkd#_helping_with_gitweb)) like so:

```perl
use lib (".");
require "gitweb.conf.pl";
```

Here is my `gitweb.conf.pl`, adapted from [`gitolite/contrib/gitweb/gitweb.conf`](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite/blob/pu/contrib/gitweb/gitweb.conf):
(note that I have custom paths)

```perl
# --------------------------------------------
# Per-repo authorization based on gitolite ACL
# Include this in gitweb.conf
# See doc/3-faq-tips-etc.mkd for more info

# please note that the author does not have personal experience with gitweb
# and does not use it.  Some testing may be required.  Patches welcome but
# please make sure they are tested against a "github" version of gitolite
# and not an RPM or a DEB, for obvious reasons.

# HOME of the gitolite user
my $gl_home = $ENV{HOME} = "/home/mccprdg1";

# the following variables are needed by gitolite; please edit before using

# this should normally not be anything else
$ENV{GL_RC} = "$gl_home/.gitolite.rc";
# this can have different values depending on how you installed.

# If you installed using the 'from-client' method it will be this:
$ENV{GL_BINDIR} = "$gl_home/.gitolite/src";
# if you used RPM/DEB or "root" methods it **might** be this:
#$ENV{GL_BINDIR} = "/usr/local/bin";
# if you used the "non-root" method it **might** be this:
#$ENV{GL_BINDIR} = "$gl_home/bin";
# If in doubt take a look at ~/.ssh/authorized_keys; at least one of the lines
# might contain something like:
#       command="/home/git/.gitolite/src/gl-auth-command
# and you should use whatever directory the gl-auth-command is in (in this
# example /home/git/.gitolite.src)

# finally the user name
$ENV{GL_USER} = $cgi->remote_user || "gitweb";

# now get gitolite stuff in...
unshift @INC, $ENV{GL_BINDIR};
require gitolite_rc;    gitolite_rc -> import;
require gitolite;       gitolite    -> import;

# set project root etc. absolute paths
$ENV{GL_REPO_BASE_ABS} = ( $REPO_BASE =~ m(^/) ? $REPO_BASE : "$gl_home/$REPO_BASE" );
$projects_list = $projectroot = $ENV{GL_REPO_BASE_ABS};

$export_auth_hook = sub {
    my $repo = shift;
    # gitweb passes us the full repo path; so we strip the beginning
    # and the end, to get the repo name as it is specified in gitolite conf
    return unless $repo =~ s/^\Q$projectroot\E\/?(.+)\.git$/$1/;

    # check for (at least) "R" permission
    my ($perm, $creator) = &repo_rights($repo);
    return ($perm =~ /R/);
};
```

---

As mentioned in the [admin doc](http://sitaramc.github.com/gitolite/doc/2-admin.html#gwd), my `.gitolite.rc` file contains:

```
$PROJECTS_LIST = $ENV{HOME} . "/projects.list";
```

, which references the same `reponames.git` repositories than the ones present in the directory `$projects_list` defined in the `gitweb.conf.pl` (`$projects_list` being equals to `$gl_home/repositories`):

```
> grep REPO_BASE *
gitweb.conf.pl:$ENV{GL_REPO_BASE_ABS} = ( $REPO_BASE =~ m(^/) ? $REPO_BASE : "$gl_home/$REPO_BASE" );
gitweb.conf.pl:$projects_list = $projectroot = $ENV{GL_REPO_BASE_ABS};
```

`REPO_BASE` being defined in the `.gitolite.rc` file:

```
> grep REPO_BA .gitolite*
.gitolite.rc:$REPO_BASE="repositories";
```